# Listing all the possible echelon forms of a $3\times 3$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

My approach.

Let $a$ denote a leading entry and $b$ be any value.

The possible echelon forms of a $3\times 3$ matrix are:

$$\begin{bmatrix} a & b & b \\ 0 & a & b \\ 0 & 0 & a\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} a & b & b \\ 0 & a & b \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} a & b & b \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & a & b \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & a \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$

If these are correct, we can pretty much augment any matrix of the appropriate size to the right of these matrices and these matrices would remain in echelon form right? Even if suppose for the fifth matrix I augment it with something that will make the system inconsistent, i.e.

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & a \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 5 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

is still in echelon form. Or am I mistaken somewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

here are the rrefs of $3 \times 3:$

of rank $3:$ $\quad \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1}$

of rank $2: \quad\pmatrix{1&0&x\\0&1&x\\0&0&0} , \pmatrix{1&x&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0}, \pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0}$

of rank $1: \quad\pmatrix{1&x&x\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}, \pmatrix{0&1&x\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}, \pmatrix{0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}$

of rank $0: \quad \pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}$

where $x$ represents an arbitrary number. hopefully this is complete.

Comment: Note that these are _reduced_ row echelon matrices, whereas it looks like the form the OP is speaking about doesn't require zeroes above the pivot entries. Nonetheless, each of these correspond to a form that _should_ be on his list.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, thanks for verifying my list. i enjoy your expository answers.

Comment: x @abel: Thank you! (And one way to verify that the list is complete is that the shape of a reduced row echelon matrix (to the level of abstraction shown here) depends only on which of the columns contain a pivot element. Since each of 3 the columns may either contain a pivot or not, there should be $2^3=8$ different shapes, which is also what this list has).

Comment: @HenningMakholm, nice. i see a pascal triangle there.

Comment: x @abel: Indeed you do, since for example each of the rank-2 shapes corresponds to a choice of which two columns to put the pivots in, which has $\binom32$ choices. The sum of the $n$th row of Pascal's triangle is $2^n$.

Comment: Why do you have a single $x$ variable, shouldn't the different entries be different in general?